# How to get the average of a specific value in Django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, aggregate-functions

I have two models 'Teams' and 'Members'.

One of the fields in Members is 'favorite_team' and a field in Teams is 'favorite_avg'

I am trying to get an average of the favorite_team field by entering in a value.

I am trying to find a better/faster way to do this:

```
    all_members = Members.objects.all().count()
    giants_fans = Members.objects.filter(favorite_team='New York Giants').count()

    team = Teams.objects.get(name='New York Giants')
    team.favorite_avg = giants_fans/all_members
    team.save()
```

Comment: Can you share Teams and Members models?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be much better models design for Members.favorite_team to be ForeignKey to Teams model instead of CharField. That would make it easier to annotate/aggregate data and change in name of team would not require change in all Members favorite_team CharField.
But for your current models you can use `Subquery` and `Cast`

```
from django.db.models import Count, Subquery, OuterRef, FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

members_count = Members.objects.count()

Teams.objects.update(
    favorite_avg=Cast(
        Subquery(
            Members.objects.filter(favorite_team=OuterRef('name'))
            .values('favorite_team')
            .annotate(count_members=Count('favorite_team'))
            .values('count_members')
        ),
        FloatField(),
    )
    / members_count
)
```

This will update all your teams with ration of Members having specific team as favourite to members_count